How to inject DbContext with dynamic SQL connection based on a value received from other system in a controller
Using C#, ASP.NET 8.0 (MVC), EF Core 8.0 (new to EF Core).
I have a situation where I have couple of database connections in AppSettings.Json.
Now I need to pass respective database connection string based on a specific value received from a 3rd party system with in a controller (e.g. HomeController).
So what is the best way to pass DbContext with appropriate connection string from a Controller using Dependency Injection.
Any sample code you can provide would help me.
Thank you in advance.
Created a database context static class, using that I am creating a DBContext within Controller. Simplified code below
public static class DbContextFactory
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string>? DbConnectionStrings { get; set; }

    public static void SetDbConnectionString(Dictionary<string, string>? dbConnectionStrings)
    {
        DbConnectionStrings = dbConnectionStrings;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext Create(string dbConnId)
    {
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationContext> optionsBuilder = new();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(DbConnectionStrings![dbConnId]);
        return new ApplicationContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}

My Controller
public IActionResult GetGroupMemebers(string userid)
{
    try
    {
        string databaseId = GetUserDatabaseFromCustomApplication(userid);
        appContext ??= DbContextFactory.Create(databaseId.ToLower());        

       IEnumerable<TeamOwner>? teamOwners = databaseService.GetTeamOwnersAsync(appContext, userid);
        
        //other application logic
        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {       
        return View("Index", grpMemVM);
    }
}


Based on your description and the code you provided, do you want to create the corresponding DbContext instance after receiving the database connection string through the controller? If so, here is my example method you can use as a reference:
In my AppSettings.json I have multiple database connection strings:
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DropdownContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DropdownContext;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "WebApplication7ContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=CCOO;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },

I create a custom IDbContextFactory interface and its implementation class:
 public interface IDbContextFactory
 {
     MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string connectionString);
 }

     public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
     {
         public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string connectionString)
         {
             var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
             optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    
             return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
         }
     }

About Mydbcontext:
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    
    public DbSet<Class> Myclass { get; set; }
}

My controller:
 public IActionResult Ondex(string dbKey)
  {
      string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString(dbKey);
      var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(connectionString);

      var data = context.Myclass.ToList();
      return View(data);
  }

When I send the correct database connection string, It can be observed that relevant information is obtained:



var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext -> using var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext

Thank you Yuning. Only one question and please accept my apologies for my knowledge ignorance on EF Core. If user closes browser will it also close underlying DBCONTEXT? Or is it always advisable to use like below
using (AppDbContext dbContext = dbContextFactory.GetDbContextForDatabase(dbID)) 
{
}


If the user closes the browser, this does not automatically close the underlying DbContext instance. The lifestyle of DbContext is managed by server-side code and is not directly controlled by the client.
And It is very important to release the DbContext after use. This ensures that all unmanaged resources are released and any events or other hooks are unregistered to prevent memory leaks while the instance remains referenced. To learn more about efcore dbcontext you can refer to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#the-dbcontext-lifetime
